# Import google contacts from google api v3

Tags: scala, gdata, google-contacts-api

My scala version is 2.10.x with JDK 7
I tried using "gdata-scala-client" but it gives me [exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18612329/exception-in-thread-main-java-lang-nosuchmethoderror-scala-collection-javacon), I found that it is a bug reported to [gdata-scala-client](http://code.google.com/p/gdata-scala-client/issues/detail?id=5)  Is there any alternate method to import google contacts in scala cersion 2.10.x??

Please Help